# How to change the background colors in React with a useState in if statement

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

```
const [temperatureColor, setTemperatureColor] = useState({color:"navyblue"});

const TemperaturIncrement = () => {
    if (temperatureValue === 30) return;

    const newTemperature =  temperatureValue + 1;

    setTemperatureValue(newTemperature)

    if(newTemperature >= 15 ){
        setTemperatureColor({ color: isChecked ? "navyblue" : "red" });
    } 
}

const TemperaturDecrement = () => {
    setTemperatureValue(temperatureValue - 1)
}
```

I wanted to changed background color using useState in if statement

Answer (score 2):

You should make your state variable a string one like below

```
const [temperatureColor, setTemperatureColor] = useState("navyblue");
```

and update that value like below

```
setTemperatureColor(isChecked ? "navyblue" : "red");
```

and use the string value inside your JSX like below

```
<View style={{ color: temperatureColor }}></View>
```

Hope this helps.